# How do I use an exisiting function pass from my LLVM - pass?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, clang

I have been using LLVM and I was confused how to use a different already present pass from my own pass ? Precisely my program needs Dominance Frontier Calculation for any given instruction. LLVM already has the Dominance function Class that is implemented as a function pass. How can i invoke it/make use of it in my Module Pass ?

Comment: Have you checked the docs? Because the last time I checked, the answer was there: http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html

Comment: Add `AU.addRequired<DominanceFrontier>();` to your pass `getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) ` method.

Comment: The documentation is really obscure and I had real problems deciphering it. An example would have helped.

Comment: What is your version of LLVM? What kind of information do you want to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WARNING: I have no real experience and answer may be incorrect or outdated. (it is based largely on outdated LLVM sources: [version 1.3](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/tags/RELEASE_13/lib/Transforms/Scalar/PRE.cpp).)

Add an include:

```
#include "llvm/Analysis/DominanceFrontier.h"
```

If your pass if Function Pass, add to your class the method (if it is not implemented):

```
virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const { }
```

And put this into it:

```
 AU.addRequired<DominanceFrontier>();
```

Then, in your class `runOnFunction` method:

```
 DominanceFrontier *DF = &getAnalysis<DominanceFrontier>();
```

After this you can use:

```
    BasicBlock *BB = /* some BB */;
    DominanceFrontier::iterator DFI = DF->find(BB);
```