# AnalysisUsage error in llvm

Tags: llvm

This is what im getting when I'm trying to use DomFrontier information from my pass:

```
opt: /home/smriti/Thesis/llvm/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h:214:
AnalysisType && llvm::Pass::getAnalysisID(AnalysisID) const [AnalysisType = llvm::DominanceFrontier]:
Assertion `ResultPass && "getAnalysis*() called on an analysis that was not " "'required' by pass!"' failed`
```

I've put this within my pass which derives from the module pass:

```
virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {AU.addRequired<DominanceFrontier>();}
```

And my runOnFunction contains the following:

```
DominanceFrontier& DF = getAnalysis<DominanceFrontier>(FF);
```

Please let me know if I have problem with these? Or should I attach the entire code of the pass if the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: This question have already been asked (and even about the exact same pass) here: [How do I use an exisiting function pass from my LLVM - pass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333726/how-do-i-use-an-exisiting-function-pass-from-my-llvm-pass). Although it refers to an older LLVM version, the answer there is still accurate as of this time.

Comment: I have used the exact statements from the specified link only.The pass still gives an assertion failure defined in PassAnalysisSupport.h . I cant understand what its about. Please help

Comment: In that case, could you edit the question to show the code of your `getAnalysisUsage()` method and the code snippet where you invoke `getAnalysis()`?

Comment: Ive used addReuired<DominanceFrontier>(); and getAnalysis<DominanceFrontier>(FF). Ive inserted the colons because it was not displaying Dom..Frontier . Sorry im new at writing here.

Comment: I confess your code looks fine to me. Maybe you should indeed show the entire file...

Comment: You could try `getAnalysisIfAvailable<DominanceFrontier>(FF)` -- it returns a pointer or NULL if the analysis is not available. If you get NULL, try running `opt -debug-pass=Structure -load <yourlib> -yourpass` to see the order of invoked passes. Then you could also try explicitly telling `opt` via the command line to run the DomFrontier pass before yours.